# How to pause an "if" but simultaneously run another "if" routine?

Tags: python, time

For the first "if" statement, I want the GPIO to be low for 5 seconds and then high for 1 second. At the same time, I do not want to sleep to pause the second if statement. I.e. I want the script to be able to execute the ss.moisture if statement while the photo_volt() is pausing.

```
try:
    while True:
        if photo_volt() < 1.6:
            GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.LOW)
            sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.HIGH)
            sleep(1)
        elif photo_volt() > 1.6:
            GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.HIGH)
        if ss.moisture_read() < 350
            GPIO.output(RELAY_2, GPIO.LOW)
            sleep(5)
         elif ss.moisture_read() > 350
            GPIO.output(RELAY_2, GPIO.HIGH)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: How often do you really want the `photo_volt()` and `moisture_read()` checks to be performed?

Comment: I want it to be performed often (every few seconds)

Comment: I think the behaviour you want is still under-specified, but I've had a go at a thread-free solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a new thread for the pair of GPIO calls.

```
from threading import Thread


def relay1_low_high():
    GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(5)
    GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.HIGH)


try:
    while True:
        if photo_volt() < 1.6:
            Thread(target=low_high).start()
        elif photo_volt() > 1.6:
            GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.HIGH)

        ...
finally:  # You probably want to do this no matter why the `try` statement exits.
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Now, unlike in the OP's code, the `photo_volt` check is performed *very* frequently. This may or may not be what the OP wants, but note that there needs to be some sort of refractory-period logic in spawning threads:  if the reading is <1.6 on the first iteration, it's really likely to be <1.6 on the next iteration a few microseconds later, and so on...That's a lotta threads.  Also, am I the only one thinking "what if it's **exactly** equal to 1.6....?"

Comment: That's incredibly clever! Thank you for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question-- is it an issue to spawn too many threads? Is there a way to "close" a  thread?

Comment: if those GPIO calls are not blocking, you don't actually need threads but can use coroutines: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: @noobquestionsonly - number of threads is not a problem if you have a few, not hundreds or thousands. but it's best to avoid threads when you don't really need them.

Comment: One option would be to wait on the thread (via its `join` method) after the second `if` statement (or at the end of the loop body), so that you don't try to start a new thread while the first one is still running.

Comment: There's also the possibility of decoupling the code, having separate threads (each with its own infinite loop) for each relay, raising and lowering them independently of each other.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sprinkling `sleep` within your `if` blocks (which halts execution) you could use counters and a single `sleep` command at the end of the loop which is only used to pause at 1 second intervals. Something like this:

```
counter = 0
while True:
    counter += 1
    if counter == 1:
        if photo_volt() < 1.6:
            GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.LOW)
        elif photo_volt() > 1.6:
            GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.HIGH)
        if ss.moisture_read() < 350
            GPIO.output(RELAY_2, GPIO.LOW)
        elif ss.moisture_read() > 350
            GPIO.output(RELAY_2, GPIO.HIGH)
    if counter == 5:
        counter = 0
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

@dryliketoast 's answer is best if it works for this - certainly best if you can just do it with logic, without needing parallel execution.

anyhow, here is what a version with async task might look like - similar to logic of threads, but without using threads

```py
import asyncio
import random

def photo_volt():
  return random.choice([1,2])

async def relay1_low_high():
  while True:
    print("Relay1: GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.LOW)")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Relay1: GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.HIGH)")

async def main():
  task = asyncio.create_task(relay1_low_high())
  try:
      while True:
          if photo_volt() < 1.6:
              await task
          elif photo_volt() > 1.6:
              print("Main: GPIO.output(RELAY_1, GPIO.HIGH)")

  finally:  # You probably want to do this no matter why the `try` statement exits.
      print("GPIO.cleanup()")

asyncio.run(main())
```

maybe not exactly right but in the direction, is on repl.it at: https://repl.it/repls/DoubleDeepskyblueCommas

that's relatively new python feats since 3.5, earlier there were generators with yield, https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems here is that we don't have a specification of the *complete* behaviour of the system (for example, after each *high* `photo_volt()` or `moisture_read()` reading, is there a minimum length of time the corresponding relay should remain `HIGH`,  like there is for `LOW`...?).   But here's an example of how it *could* work.  I'll use independent queues of events for the two relays, without threads (I have no idea if the `GPIO` library is going to be thread-safe).

```
import time
import functools # we'll use functools.partial to "pre-bake" our GPIO.output calls


def check_queue(queue, t):
    while True:
        if not queue:
            return True              # Return True to indicate "this queue is empty: feel free to take new readings and add more commands"
        first = queue[0]
        if isinstance(first, float): # A numeric entry in the queue means "do nothing until the clock reaches this number"
            if t < first:
                return False         # Return False to indicate "commands are still pending in this queue: don't take any more readings yet"
            else:
                queue.pop(0)         # Time's up: immediately proceed to the next item in the queue
        else:                        # Any non-numeric queue entry is assumed to be a command for immediate execution
            command = queue.pop(0)
            command()

try:

    relay1_commands = []
    relay2_commands = []

    while True:
        t = time.time()  # current time

        if check_queue(relay1_commands, t):
            if photo_volt() < 1.6:
                relay1_commands += [
                    functools.partial(GPIO.output, RELAY_1, GPIO.LOW),
                    t + 5.0,   # wait until 5 seconds from now (no more photo_volt readings or outputs on RELAY_1 till then)
                    functools.partial(GPIO.output, RELAY_1, GPIO.HIGH),
                    t + 6.0,   # this is literally what the question asks for, but is it necessary?

                    # so, after a low photo_volt() reading, RELAY_1 should be constantly LOW for
                    # at least 5 seconds, then automatically HIGH (regardless of photo_volt state)
                    # for at least 1 second
                ]
            else:
                relay1_commands += [
                    functools.partial(GPIO.output, RELAY_1, GPIO.HIGH),
                    t + 1.0,
                    # after a high photo_volt() reading, RELAY_1 should be constantly HIGH for
                    # at least.... what?  That's not specified in the question. Here I've arbitrarily
                    # said 1 second.
                ]

        if check_queue(relay2_commands, t):
            if ss.moisture_read() < 350:
                relay2_commands += [
                    functools.partial(GPIO.output, RELAY_2, GPIO.LOW),
                    t + 5.0,  # wait until then (no more photo_volt readings or outputs on RELAY_2)

                    # so, after a low ss.moisture() reading, RELAY_2 should be constantly LOW for
                    # at least 5 seconds, but unlike RELAY_1 there shouldn't be an automatic HIGH
                    # period after that (that's what the question appears to specify)
                ]
            else:
                relay2_commands += [
                    functools.partial(GPIO.output, RELAY_2, GPIO.HIGH),
                    t + 1.0,
                    # after a high ss.moisture() reading, RELAY_2 should be constantly HIGH for
                    # at least.... what?  That's not specified in the question. Here I've arbitrarily
                    # said 1 second.
                ]

        time.sleep(0.001)  # or however long is appropriate between repeated checks

finally:  # as chepner says:  You probably want to do this no matter why the `try` statement exits.
    GPIO.cleanup()
```